# JSON at file:// protocol

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

So, I have to open my web app, like file. So the browser opens  `.html` file and at the adres bar protocol used is `file://`. But at the script I have to open `.json` file and load it to variable.

I have tried `$.ajax` request with data type `jsonp`, I have tried `requirejs` who kind a load file but gets syntax error from json file so it doesnt load into variable. Same happens if I just do this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/.json"></script>
```

Is there another way? App doesn't use PHP it needs to run from `file://` protocol with not changing browser settings.

Thanks

Comment: You cannot access local file from browser for obvious security reason. So is `path/to/.json` local path or pointing to any server?

Comment: Yes the file ir local. The computers where the app will run is not connected to internet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can create a `.js` file and adds the `json` data to a `var` and get access to that var

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/data.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE .. EXAMPLE**

```
var text = '{"employees":[' +
'{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe" },' +
'{"firstName":"Anna","lastName":"Smith" },' +
'{"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones" }]}';
```

Comment: Show an example of what the file should contain. He tried something like this, but obviously didn't format the file correctly.

Comment: Are you sure you can access local file from browser?

Comment: @A.Wolff calling the JS file from the html, and accessing the var initiated inside won't be as accessing a local file from browser, it will act like adding a plugin

Comment: @A.Wolff in script tag this available, not working just ajax call

Comment: I have thouth about this, but the file will be overwriten time by time. But I will keep this as a option.

Answer (score 2):

Embed the data directly into the page.

There's no network, so it won't cause a performance penalty. It's static, so you don't lose the ability to generate it dynamically.

Comment: And many browsers (like chrome) have issues with ajax requests on the `file://` protocol.

Comment: And I forgot to tell that, because its a Goverment Institution there will be just Explorer 11. :D